# Cascaded aggregator not returning message

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration to pull in different account details from external systems concurrently (using taskmanager) and aggregate it into one account object. For that, I will have to do two levels of splits of message and after fetching need to aggregate at two levels. I am using simple pojos for splitter, router and aggregator implementations. And I am implementing correlation strategy and using a simple message group but not implementing any release strategy. For some reason, my messages are getting lost at the second aggregator. When I debug, I can see the messages coming on to the second level aggregator from first level aggregators, but it is unable to pass those messages on to the output channel.

One more observation is that, if there is only one message, I am getting the output. But of any conditions which result in more than one message to get aggregated, I dont see any output and the threads are hung.

Any help appreciated!!

Here is the context definitions.

```
    <bean id="accountManager" class="<package>.AccountManager"/>

<int:gateway id="accountBuilder"
    service-interface="<package>.AccountBuilder" default-request-channel="accountRequest"  default-reply-channel="allAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="accountRequest"/>
<int:channel id="allAccounts"/>
<int:splitter input-channel="accountRequest" output-channel="accountRequests" ref="accountSplitter" method="split"/>

<int:channel id="accountRequests">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="accountServiceTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:router input-channel="accountRequests" ref="accountRouter" method="routeAccountRequests">
    <int:mapping channel="retailRequest"/>
    <int:mapping channel="manualRequest"/>
</int:router>

<bean id="accountMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />

<bean id="searchResultMessageStoreReaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="accountMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="2000" />
</bean>

<!-- **************************************************************************** -->
<!-- **************************** RETAIL ACCOUNTS ******************************* -->
<!-- **************************************************************************** -->

<int:channel id="retailRequest"/>

<int:splitter input-channel="retailRequest" output-channel="retailAccountRequests" ref="retailAccountSplitter" method="split"/>

<int:channel id="retailAccountRequests">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="accountServiceTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:router input-channel="retailAccountRequests" ref="retailAccountRouter" method="routeRetailAccountRequests">
    <int:mapping channel="retailAccountDataRequest"/>
    <int:mapping channel="retailAccountDetailsRequest"/>
    <int:mapping channel="retailAccountPositionsRequest"/>
</int:router>

<int:channel id="retailAccountDataRequest"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="retailAccountDataRequest" ref="retailAccountDataMapper"
                       method="getRetailAccountData" output-channel="aggregatedRetailAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="retailAccountDetailsRequest"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="retailAccountDetailsRequest" ref="retailAccountDetailsMapper"
                       method="getRetailAccountDetails" output-channel="aggregatedRetailAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="retailAccountPositionsRequest"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="retailAccountPositionsRequest" ref="retailAccountPositionsMapper"
                       method="getRetailAccountPositions" output-channel="aggregatedRetailAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="aggregatedRetailAccounts" />
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatedRetailAccounts"
    ref="retailAccountAggregator" method="aggregate" output-channel="aggregatedAccounts"
    message-store="accountMessageStore" expire-groups-upon-completion="true"/>

<!-- ************************** END RETAIL ACCOUNTS ***************************** -->

<!-- **************************************************************************** -->
<!-- **************************** MANUAL ACCOUNTS ******************************* -->
<!-- **************************************************************************** -->

<int:channel id="manualRequest"/>

<int:splitter input-channel="manualRequest" output-channel="manualAccountRequests" ref="manualAccountSplitter" method="split"/>

<int:channel id="manualAccountRequests">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="accountServiceTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:router input-channel="manualAccountRequests" ref="manualAccountRouter" method="routeManualAccountRequests">
    <int:mapping channel="manualAccountDataRequest"/>
    <int:mapping channel="manualAccountDetailsRequest"/>
    <int:mapping channel="manualAccountPositionsRequest"/>
</int:router>

<int:channel id="manualAccountDataRequest"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="manualAccountDataRequest" ref="manualAccountDataMapper"
                       method="getManualAccountData" output-channel="aggregatedManualAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="manualAccountDetailsRequest"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="manualAccountDetailsRequest" ref="manualAccountDetailsMapper"
                       method="getManualAccountDetails" output-channel="aggregatedManualAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="manualAccountPositionsRequest"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="manualAccountPositionsRequest" ref="manualAccountPositionsMapper"
                       method="getManualAccountPositions" output-channel="aggregatedManualAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="aggregatedManualAccounts"/>
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatedManualAccounts"
ref="manualAccountAggregator" method="aggregate" output-channel="aggregatedAccounts"
message-store="accountMessageStore" expire-groups-upon-completion="true"/>

<!-- ************************** END MANUAL ACCOUNTS ***************************** -->

<int:channel id="aggregatedAccounts" />
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatedAccounts" ref="accountAggregator"
    method="aggregate" output-channel="allAccounts" message-store="accountMessageStore"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true" />




<bean id="accountServiceTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="250" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="500" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're more likely to get useful answers if you include some distilled sample code in this question so we can reproduce the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for further advice.

Answer (score 1):

When using the standard correlation header (`correlationId`), nested sequence details (`correlationId`, `sequenceSize`, `sequenceNumber`) are maintained automatically, by the framework, in a stack which is pushed (in the subsequent splitter) and popped (in the aggregator) under a header `sequenceDetails`. See [MessageBuilder.pushSequenceDetails()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/3.0.x/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/support/MessageBuilder.java#L213) and the corresponding `popSequenceDetails()` just below.

If you are using non-standard correlation, you are responsible for keeping it straight, in a similar fashion, when nesting splitters.

Non-standard correlation is not a problem, as long as you store the data in the `correlationId` header, if you want the framework to handle nested splits.

As always, DEBUG logging and following messages through the flow will generally identify these kinds of problems.

PS: Always try to indicate the version you are using.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for your reply. I have used the correlation strategy in aggregators at both levels. However, I have only used custom  correlationIds to track the messages. Is releaseStrategy the right place to track the custom sequenceSize and sequenceNumber? Will you be able to point me to an example code? Thanks again!

Comment: and I am using 4.0.0.M2 version of spring integration.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to deal with it would be to add a `<header-enricher/>` right before the second splitter to save off the previous aggregator's headers in other header(s). Then use another one just after the 'inner' aggregator to restore the outer aggregator's headers. Bear in mind, though, you can't use custom `sequence*` headers with the default `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`; it uses the standard headers.

Comment: Gary, Thank you! Your suggestion worked. I am getting back messages out of the outer aggregator. However, after the messages are received, the threads that are spawned by the task executor are still running indefinitely. I am using "org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" for multi threading for routers at both levels.

Comment: That's because your `core-pool-size` is 25. Threads over the core pool size will terminate after `keepaliveSeconds` (default 60) have elapsed.

Comment: The TaskExecutor threads are terminating after the keepaliveSeconds is elapsed. But the task-scheduler threads are not. I am running in debug mode on my eclipse... with each request I see more tomcat-http daemon threads stacking up and not terminating even after the keepaliveSeconds is elapsed.

Comment: The default task scheduler uses a core pool size of 10 threads. The documentation explains how to replace the default scheduler if you wish to use different settings. http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler. Tomcat http threads are controlled by Tomcat and are outside the scope of Spring Integration configuration.